# Setup a graph from a NxM grid to apply A* search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, a-star

I have to find the simple path

[image: Like the one in this link]

with the least amount of turns. To do that I found online that the best solution is to apply a A* search algorithm and setting the node of the graph linked to my grid by some state of it that allows me to explore the grid.
The point is that I can't find a way to correctly set up a graph like that, if you could explain it to me, maybe even with an example (even not on my grid) so I can understand the process it would be a lifesaver.

P.S. every tile on the grid can be the last one and

Comment: yeah, but the A* is a search algorithm i have no finishing point in my grid

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear- do you need to visit every square on the grid? Is a solution guaranteed to exist? Are you given a start and end point? More importantly, this post is currently a task, not a question. Homework questions should ask about problems with an *existing* implementation; see [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/16757174) and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When building a graph from a grid to make pathfinding:

- Each node in the graph represents a cell of the grid.
- Each edge, a possible movement between cells.

So your setup algorithm must iterate all the cells in the grid, adding them as nodes if they are free and edges to their accesible neighbours.

To implement a graph, you use its adjacency matrix, sparse or not.

This is the algorithm in pseudocode, using an unoptimized sparse adjacency matrix and identifying each node by the coordinates of its equivalent cell in the grid in a string form:

```js
graph = empty_dictionary()

// iterate the grid
for r in grid.rows
  for c in grid.columns

    // initialize a new node
    nodeID = to_string([r,c])
    graph[nodeID] = []

    // add the adjacent free neighbours
    if grid.isFree(r-1, c) 
      graph[nodeID].append(to_string([r-1, c]))
    if grid.isFree(r, c-1) 
      graph[nodeID].append(to_string([r, c-1]))
    if grid.isFree(r+1, c) 
      graph[nodeID].append(to_string([r+1, c]))
    if grid.isFree(r, c+1) 
      graph[nodeID].append(to_string([r, c+1]))
```

Where `isFree` returns true iff the coordinates are not out of bounds and correspond to a free cell.